# $geoWithin with mongoDB aggregate causes BadValue bad geo query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, geospatial

I am trying to use a $geoWithin query in a aggregate pipeline, but I am getting a an

```
MongoError: exception: bad query: BadValue bad geo query: { $geoWithin: {    $box: [ [ "13.618240356445312", "51.01343066212905" ], [ "13.865432739257812",   "51.09662294502995" ] ] } }
```

My query is:

```
{ 
    $match: {
        'gps.coordinates.matched': {
            $geoWithin: {
                $box: [
                    [ swlng, swlat ],
                    [ nelng , nelat ]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},
{ $project : {shortGeohash: {$substr: ["$gps.geohash.original", 0, 11]}}},
{ $group: {_id: "$shortGeohash", count: {$sum:1}, originalDoc:{$push: "$$ROOT"}}}
```

The query only for `$geoWithin` as well `$project...,$group` work well on their own, but combined the error occurs.

Comment: Hmm. Are you actually wrapping your pipeline with `[]` as a proper array identifier? Not to mention that `$$ROOT` is not doing what I think you expect it does here. It's just the "whole" document in the "current" stage and not the "original" document as it was before you modified with `$project`

Comment: I did not before, but wrapping it an array causes the same error, no changes there. Indeed did `$$ROOT` not work as i intended it to do, but it at least it gives me the `ObjectId`, which works fine for me.

Comment: You would do better to edit your question and provide examples that people can test and reproduce. Right now I just say, "works for me". But do take that `$$ROOT` comment to heart here as you are doing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your query and it seems to actually work. I executed the query over a collection with documents such as this.

```
[{
    "_id" : "5a2404674eb6d938c8f44856",
    "code" : "M.12345",
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            41.9009789, 
            12.5010465
        ]
    }
},
...
]
```

The aggregation pipeline is this.

```
{ 
    $match: {
        'loc': {
            $geoWithin: {
                $box: [
                    [ 0, 0 ],
                    [ 5, 5 ]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},
{ $project : {subCode: {$substr: ["$code", 0, 4]}}},
{ $group: {_id: "$subCode", count: {$sum:1}, originalDoc:{$push: "$$ROOT"}}}
```

One of the results is this.

```
{
    "_id" : "M.10",
    "count" : 12.0,
    "originalDoc" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "5a2481c44eb6d92b6895633a",
            "subCode" : "M.10"
        },
        .... //11 more items
    ]
}
```

Results are correctly returned with mongod v3.4.9.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like $geoWithin is not one of the [aggregation operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/).

[The reference example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#within-a-polygon) works, sadly, I am not aware of a way to add an aggregation to that.